# Ubuntu Software Center disappeared. Reinstalling it doesn't work

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu, I have 15.10 installed but Software Center disappeared.

I tried to run this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

But Im getting this error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This post should have the answer you seek : [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Did you recently add any ppas?

Comment: I don't exactly remember but I was trying to install python idle

Comment: Did you follow any tutorials, that you can point us to?

Comment: I was just googling for the problems I was facing here's what I did: Installed pygame got error Mksd tool while installing android studio fixed it. Then installed python by downloading it from python.org and compiling it then got error of not having fixed administrative locals then fixed it by googling it and now getting this error. And now I have restarted the Ubuntu nothing is showing it's just the two folders

Comment: Please run `apt-cache policy python python3` and [edit] your question to paste the output (as text using CTRL+K to apply code formatting, not as screenshot). Messing around with Python is dangerous if you don't know what to do. Accidentally damaging the system wide python installations will make many commands stop working.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is showing it's just the two folders "?

Comment: No unity no dash nothing not even terminal I tried the guide it tells to go to hard terminal and running compizconfig-settings-manager but there also it is giving unment python error what to do